# отображение товаров из сетки через базу данных

Tags: php, веб-программирование, вёрстка, phpmyadmin

Здраствуйте, я решил, для практики в веб-программировании, создать интернет-магазин. Он должен с помощью базы данных phpmyadmin размещать товары в сетку. Все работает, но есть небольшая проблема: Каждая позиция начинается с новой строки и в итоге правая часть магазина пуста, а левая заполнена товаром    [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
<?php
$details = get_details_all();
foreach ($details as $single):  ?>
<?php $category_name = get_category_by_id($single["category_id"]); ?>
<?php $brand_name = get_brand_by_id($single["brand_id"]); ?>

<main> 
  <section class="text-center mb-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="view overlay">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $single["img"];?>">
            <hr>
            <a href="/product.php?id=<?php echo $single["id"];?>">
              <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <a href="/product.php?id=<?php echo $single["id"];?>" class="grey-text">
              <h5><?php echo $single["title"];?></h5>
            </a>
            <h5>
              <strong><?php echo $brand_name; ?>
              <a href="/categories.php">
                </span></a>
              </strong>
            </h5>
            
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold blue-text">
              <strong><?php echo $single["price"];?></strong>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неправильная конструкция, в добавок был не закрыт тег `span` (там где ссылка на `categories.php`), код ниже может решить проблему

```
<main>
<?php
$details = get_details_all();
foreach ($details as $single):  
  $category_name = get_category_by_id($single["category_id"]);
  $brand_name = get_brand_by_id($single["brand_id"]);
?>
  <section class="text-center mb-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="view overlay">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $single["img"];?>">
            <hr>
            <a href="/product.php?id=<?php echo $single["id"];?>">
              <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <a href="/product.php?id=<?php echo $single["id"];?>" class="grey-text">
              <h5><?php echo $single["title"];?></h5>
            </a>
            <h5>
              <strong><?php echo $brand_name; ?>
                <a href="/categories.php">
                  <span></span>
                </a>
              </strong>
            </h5>
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold blue-text">
              <strong><?php echo $single["price"];?></strong>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</main>
```

Comment: не помогло. Я думаю, что создание четырех столбцов в таблице помогло бы, но я не знаю, как это реализовать

Comment: Ещё вопрос, вы как-то пытаетесь создать эту самую сетку?

Comment: да, но в ней <?php endforeach; ?> должен быть перед последним </div>, что бы написать новый php код со значениями новой таблицы из phpmyadmin, но тогда все товары будут хаотично разбросаны.

Comment: я сейчас попробовал это сделать и оно сработало. Ошибка была в том, что я main закрыл в конце body, после кнопок для переключения страниц. Спасибо большое! Из-за этой мелочи мучался 2 дня, даже жалко время

Comment: @Sasha, не за что, главное что решилось